# Hive query : How to assign one table column to another table all columns?

Tags: hive

I want to merge two tables with different schemas.

Table A like below,

```
ID||Name
---------
1|Kay
4|Jan
6|Mack
```

Table B like below,

```
Status
----------
Approved
```

I want table like below.

```
ID||Name||Status
------------------
1|Kay|Approved
4|Jan|Approved
6|Mack|Approved
```

How can I get this by using a hive query?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no join key between two tables ?

Comment: @Jaytiger no join key

Comment: `cross join` will get you what you want but not sure your system allows it.